# Stopping a scroll function from triggering multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a script that pulls data from the database and displays it when the user nears the bottom of the page.

**The problem:**
When the user reaches the bottom, the script should only return one post back, but instead, multiple requests are being made, causing all of the posts to be being pulled from the database at a rapid pace, which in turn returns them in the wrong order.

My question is, is there anyone who knows how to stop it from going haywire and prevent the spamming of articles?

**Note:**

I'm not looking to completely cut the AJAX requests off once one has been made, as this script is an 'infinite scroll', pulling articles one by one from the database when the user reaches the bottom.

Thanks in advance, Rich.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {     
      $(window).scroll(function() {
           if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
                $('div#loadMoreArticles').show( function(){         
                     $.ajax({
                          url: "loadMoreArticles.php?lastArticle="+ $(".postedArticle:last").attr('id') ,
                          success: function(html) {
                               if(html){       
                                    $("#postedArticle").append(html);
                                    $('div#loadMoreArticles').hide();       
                               } else { 
                                    $('div#loadMoreArticles').replaceWith("<p>There are no more articles.</p>");
                               }
                          }
                     });
                });
           }
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining handler as named function , using `.off()` to detach `scroll` event before `$.ajax()` call , reattach `scroll` event after `$.ajax()` completes

```
function scroller() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
            $(this).off("scroll.ajax");
            $('div#loadMoreArticles').show( function(){         
                 $.ajax({
                      url: "loadMoreArticles.php?lastArticle="+ $(".postedArticle:last").attr('id') ,
                      success: function(html) {
                           if(html){       
                                $("#postedArticle").append(html);
                                $('div#loadMoreArticles').hide();       
                           } else { 
                                $('div#loadMoreArticles').replaceWith("<p>There are no more articles.</p>");
                           };
                           // setTimeout(function() {
                             $(window).on("scroll.ajax", scroller)
                           // }, 500)
                      }
                 });
            });
       }
  }

$(window).on("scroll.ajax", scroller);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var AjaxRequestOn;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
      $('div#loadMoreArticles').show(function() {
        if (!AjaxRequestOn) {
          AjaxRequestOn = $.ajax({
            url: "/",
            success: function(html) {

            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Just use a variable to set the ajax request , when the first ajax is set then if user again scroll up and comes down then the variable has some value so we should not do the call again(check if loop before ajax call). If the variable is not defined then we have to make the call to server. so this results in only one call to server.

Comment: The function is an infinite scroll. So it's only returning my LIMIT in the PHP query through AJAX with your suggestion. +1 though.

Comment: @Filthy_Rich Inside the success function just set AjaxRequestOn = false.